# Does AJAX same origin policy apply to domain of HTML page or JavaScript file, or both?

Tags: javascript, ajax, cross-domain

If I host a page at **www.example.com/page.html**, and it has this line:

```
<script src="http://sub.example.com/script.js"></script>
```

...In that script, can I use `XMLHTTPRequest` to load JSON data from **sub.example.com**? Or does the same origin policy only count the HTML page's server as the origin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the domain of the *document*, not of the JS file.  You can see what the current domain is by looking at the value of [`document.domain`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.domain).

Comment: @AlienWebguy Not sure what I was referring to, but yes, indeed.